# php-fastcgi.socket does not exist

Tags: nginx, php, fastcgi

I am following [this tutorial](https://linode.com/docs/websites/nginx/nginx-and-phpfastcgi-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin), and have gotten thus far:

I have installed the following packages using `apt-get install nginx php5-cli php5-cgi spawn-fcgi psmisc`. Despite installing PHP FastCGI, I do not have the following directory on my server for my `fastcgi_pass`:

```
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fastcgi/php-fastcgi.socket;
```

How can I fix this issue? Am I meant to make the `fastcgi_pass` my server's IP address, or should it be as shown in the tutorial?

Comment: Are you obliged to use fastcgi? php-fpm should be much better.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create the folder `/var/run/php-fastcgi/` and set the owner to the account that nginx is set to use.  That will allow nginx to create `php-fastcgi.socket` for you.

Please see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/139639) for further information.